# No module named 'reportlab' when running from cmd, but working if run from IDE

Tags: python, cmd, conda

I am using PyCharm and a conda environment for one project. It is working fine when running the python file directly from PyCharm.

Now I am trying to add some args arguments. However, when I run the code from cmd I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab'
```

The error pops up because of the import lines like the following one:

```
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
```

I don't know why it happens, because I have the environment active in the cmd and when I run `conda list` it seems that reportlab is correctly installed (it should be as it works when running from PyCharm):

```
reportlab                 3.6.10                   pypi_0    pypi
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but if I execute the script by doing `python script.py` instead of `script.py` it works.

PS: Instead of executing `python script.py --argument1 arg1 --argument2 arg2 ...` the solution that worked for me was adding `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the start of the script.